# Can a folder be added to the finder's sidebar in sandbox mode?

Tags: cocoa, sandbox, finder, appstore-sandbox

When sandboxing for my application is enabled, I cannot add a new folder to the Finder's sidebar. The code blow only works if sandboxing is disabled. Is it even possible to add a bookmark item(s) to the Finder with Sandboxing enabled?

```
-(void) addPathToSharedItem:(NSString *)path
{
    CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; 

    // Create a reference to the shared file list.
    LSSharedFileListRef favoriteItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL,
                                                            kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems, NULL); 
    if (favoriteItems) {
        //Insert an item to the list.
        LSSharedFileListItemRef item = LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL(favoriteItems,
                                                                     kLSSharedFileListItemLast, NULL, NULL,
                                                                     url, NULL, NULL);
        if (item){
            CFRelease(item);
        }
    }   

    CFRelease(favoriteItems);
}
```